# javafx memory consuption hints for resizing images

Tags: java, image, memory-management, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have a simple javafx application which batch manipulating with images (just resizing yet :)) It's a simple javafx form with source directory textField, destination directory textField and desired dimensions. After start of this application, simple form without any action consump aroud 65MB of memory... After start batch processing memory consuption jump to 250 MB and then raising and raising. After 700 images my application consump around 1,35GB of memory (pictures have around 3500x2600px and it's resized to 1920x1080). If I call `gc()` after each image, memory is around 300 - 350 MB. But do you have some hints to smaller memory requirements of javafx app or 350 MB is OK because Java is virtual machine. Thanks for hints. I programmed simillar application in C# around few years ago and it's consump around 60 MB of memory :) It's so big different :( But I like Java and multi-platform Appliation. And of course, I opening image in second Thread via `ImageIO.read()`, then converting to `BufferedImage()` and then I create new `BufferedImage()` with smaller dimesnions and draw original `BufferedImage()` to new - smaller image via `Graphics2D()`

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g.dispose();
```

And finally

```
ImageIO.write(backgroundThread.resize(1920, 1080), "jpg", new File(destinationPath +      f.getFileName()));
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Use the [JavaFX Image constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-double-double-boolean-boolean-boolean-) to create and resize your images, rather than using BufferedImage and ImageIO, then re-run your memory consumption test and report your result.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it's much better with memory (and slightly faster) but how I can save it then? I using `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(im, null)` but I have a strange filter on the pictures then :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [JavaFX Image constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-double-double-boolean-boolean-boolean-) to create and resize your images, rather than using [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

Memory consumption should improve as:

1. There are less format conversions happening, so intermediate formats don't need to be stored.
2. When the JavaFX Image constructor is utilized, the JavaFX javadoc specifies:

   > Images can be resized as they are loaded (for example to reduce the amount of memory consumed by the image)

---

*Answers to additional questions*

> how I can save it on disk?

Saving images to disk using JavaFX is currently (as of the initial Java 8 release), an open, unresolved feature request: [RT-18886 Implement Image writers for JavaFX](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18886).

Until RT-18886 is implemented, you will need to convert the image to a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) before you save it, in order to use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) for saving images to formats like `jpg`.  You can use [SwingFXUtils](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html) to do this.  It is still efficient to resize the image up front when you first load it into memory, which is how the JavaFX Image constructor works.

> I must also create a new Buffered Image and then draw it inside with Graphics2D.

You can load your image as a JavaFX image then paint it on a JavaFX [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html), using JavaFX [GraphicsContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#drawImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-double-double-), then [snapshot the canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) to get a new Image that you can convert to an BufferedImage and save using ImageIO.  OK, so perhaps not the most efficient process, but it does allow you to stick with (mainly) a single framework and API and avoid some potential threading issues.

> I using SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(im, null) but I have a strange filter on the pictures then

I don't know exactly what "strange filter" means, but perhaps you are seeing [RT-14647 Incorrect display of JPEG images](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14647), which was fixed in a past JavaFX update.   Try running against the latest [Java 8 development release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and see if you still get the same issue.  If not, you can create a new question with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

*Alternatives*

There is almost certainly an equivalent way of saving resized images efficiently using only BufferedImage, ImageIO and the awt/swing framework, but I am not familiar enough with that API to comment on how that might be done and I am not a fan of mixing Swing, AWT and JavaFX unless you really need to.

Comment: Yes, you have a right, very usefull but how I can save it on disk? Image created by JavaFX constructor is not `RenderedImage`. I must also create a new Buffered Image and then draw it inside with `Graphics2D`. The benefit is that loaded image are so smaller because image was resized before loading :) But convert to Buffered image is still needed.

Comment: Updated answer to address additional questions.  In future additional questions are probably best handled by creating new questions.

Comment: @Zrebec It just might be possible to create a `RenderedImage` and custom `DataBuffer` implementation that wraps a JavaFX `Image/WritableImage`, to allow ImageIO to store the image, without creating a full copy. Haven't tried though. ;-)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for replies :) Jewelsea... very usefull answer, really. Absolutly perfect